# How can I apply a LINQ query on encrypted column (using azure-keyvault ) with the ToLower function?

Tags: c#, azure, linq, c#-4.0, azure-keyvault

```
var searchEmailTrim = searchTerms.Email.Trim();

IEnumerable<Guid> customerEmail = 
    customers.Where(
        m => (m.Email.EmailAddress != null) && 
             (m.Email.EmailAddress != string.Empty) && 
             (m.Email.EmailAddress.Equals(searchEmailTrim, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => x.ID)
             .Distinct();

customers = customers.Where(m => customerEmail.Contains(m.ID));
```

Here **StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase** doesn't work because I need to check email address which is in upper case or lower case here I used azure key - vault always encryption on EmailAddress field so I can't able to use ToLower function so how can I solve this to check given EmailAddress.

In table `emailaddress` which is stored in form as it was given from the user.

Is there any way to check it?

I know that I need to fetch all of the data in the `List` without applying any conditions and then to apply the `Where` condition on this `List`, but it takes lots of memory in project and we need to do this encryption on many columns. So this isn't an optimal solution.

Are there any alternative ways to go about this?

Comment: Can you elaborate? you said, "always encryption" - do you mean the data is in SQL Server using Always Encrypted?

Comment: data is in SQL Server using Always Encrypted --> No
here domain field is encrypted using Azure key vault (CMK) so 
I can not use any internal function in SP as well as in Linq for this encrypted column 

Like in above scenario there is emailAddress field is encrypted so i can't use emailAddress.ToLower() in linq or simillar different string fn..

so is there any alternative for that?

Comment: sorry for the delay - you cannot use toLower() over ciphertext when using AE. It simply will not work because the comparison uses ciphertext and not plaintext, and you're changing the plaintext comparison.